# Which part of speech is this "earliest" in this sentence, an adjective or an adverb?

Tags: adjectives, superlatives

> [I joined a team at 8 years old, which is later than most kids start now, but was the **earliest** you could start on the girl’s team (10 and under).](http://htekidsnews.com/ask-the-author/)

I just can't decide whether this "earliest" in this sentence is an adjective or an adverb. Is there any defaulting word obstructs my judgement?

It will be greatly appreciated if your explanation or analysis would be given in detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure at all, but I'm guessing is equivalent:

> I joined a team at 8 years old, which is later than most kids start now, but was the **earliest** age that you could start on the girls’ team (10 and under).

So **earliest** would be in this case a superlative adjective.

Answer (score -2):

I would vote for an adverb in its superlative form.
Late/later are definitely adverbs in "...which is late" or the original "...which is later than...", so is the earliest.